# Windows phone webbrowser detect a number or email?

Tags: html, xaml, windows-phone

I am using a webbrowser to load a local html file in my windows phone app, however I have a number and email address inside the html, how can I set a email and phonecall task on the click events of these links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `mailto:` and `tel:` are not supported by the `WebBrowser` control on Windows Phone.

What you can do is inject Javascript in the HTML that will enumerate all `a` tags and wire up an `onclick` event. That event will call `window.external.Notify` which will in turn raise the `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebBrowser`, with the URL as a parameter.

It is a little complicated but I think it's the only option for dealing with these mailto and tel protocols on Windows Phone.

Here is the code:

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        browser.ScriptNotify += browser_ScriptNotify;
        browser.Loaded += browser_Loaded;
    }

    void browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Sample HTML code
        string html = @"<html><head></head><body><a href='mailto:test@test.com'>Envoyer un email</a><a href='tel:+3301010101'>Appeler</a></body></html>";

        // Script that will call raise the ScriptNotify via window.external.Notify
        string notifyJS = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
                                window.onload = function() {
                                    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
                                        links[i].onclick = function() {
                                            window.external.Notify(this.href);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>";

        // Inject the Javascript into the head section of the HTML document
        html = html.Replace("<head>", string.Format("<head>{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, notifyJS));

        browser.NavigateToString(html);
    }

    void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
        {
            string href = e.Value.ToLower();
            if (href.StartsWith("mailto:"))
            {
                EmailComposeTask email =  new EmailComposeTask();
                email.To = href.Replace("mailto:", string.Empty);
                email.Show();
            }
            else if (href.StartsWith("tel:"))
            {
                PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
                call.PhoneNumber = href.Replace("tel:", string.Empty);
                call.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's great! i'm getting list of Elements but onclick is not triggering. Some ideas?